# Bubble sort applet confusion in java

Tags: java, applet, bubble-sort

Can someone please help me make an applet to demonstrate bubble sort using java.
I have written a code for linear search and binary search but I can't do it for bubble sort. any sort of help will do

Comment: **Yes, someone can help you.** Does that answer your question? No? Then please explain where exactly you are stuck and what exactly the problem is which prevents you from advancing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend you can use this example hope this helps you

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/Asimpleappletclasstodemonstrateasortalgorithm.htm

This is the example for a simple applet class to demonstrate bubble sort

Comment: @user3071135 is it looks good to you

Comment: Thanks a lot. But this is so complicated :O Is there anything simpler. Im in 12th grade

Comment: Please note that one of the guidelines here about homework is that pointers are ok, but solutions are not

Comment: @user3071135 My friend please read it will help you there is simple class named BidirectionalBubbleSortAlgorithm you to read and please right click on my answer so it will be helpful for others at stackoverflow

Comment: @user3071135, please follow the disciplines of stackoverflow by upvote it